# Disputed flag for low quality answer

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, specific-answer, disputed-flags

Why was this flag regarding a low-quality answer disputed?

[why am I getting IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor') error while making print statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230855/why-am-i-getting-ioerror-9-bad-file-descriptor-error-while-making-print-st/35941587#35941587)

This "answer"  just provides a link with very little/no explanation on how to slove the problem.

I don't really care about the fact that it was disputed, I am just trying to figure out how to treat answers like this in the future:

During my review activities, I was already blocked more than once for not flagging very similar answers as "low quality", so this got me wondering what the threshold or criteria really is.

Comment: This is a tricky area. If it's a link to a confirmed bug report then it's probably ok since there's not much else to be said.

Comment: Imagine that you had this problem, searched for an answer, and came across this question. Would you not then find it helpful to have a link to a bug report in an official tracking database? It might not be the *most* helpful answer that you could find, but would you not find it at least somewhat useful? I'm pretty certain that the answer is "yes"; I certainly would find it helpful. Therefore, the implicit solution of deleting the answer is the wrong one! Maybe you should edit it, or maybe you can just downvote it, but what did you expect to happen when you raised the flag?

Comment: Has been deleted for some reason.

Comment: here is the criteria, *it is completely subjective and changes from minute to minute*, do not want to get review banned, stay away from the VLQ Review Queue. Simple as that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were quite a few users that agreed with you, looking at the [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11594148).

But (un)fortunately there were 3 users that clicked *Looks OK* and that disputed your flag.

There is plenty of discussion about what qualifies as low quality or not on meta so I'm not going to revisit that.

If those 3 reviewers visited the link they would have learned that indeed there is a bug. With that the answer has value, although very minimal. Flagging answers that contain human readable text and slightly bare some value your flags get disputed or declined.

Strangely enough the answer receives both up and down votes. I'm not a python dev but I think that answer is salvageable if this code snippet found at the end of the bug report is edited into the answer:

> [from Author: Christian Heimes (christian.heimes)](https://bugs.python.org/issue706263#msg191902)
>
> If you want to get Python 3.x style print() behavior in Python 2.7 you can have it already:
>
> ```python
> from __future__ import print_function
> import sys
> if sys.executable.endswith("pythonw.exe"):
>     sys.stdout = sys.stdout = None
>
> print("can handle sys.stdout = None just fine.")
> ```

Editing is a valid option to improve low quality posts. If not done by yourself you can nudge the OP to add it and leave a down vote until fixed.

Comment: Actually, developers established that it is not a "bug", but a "design decision".

Comment: OK, @Braiam maybe that should be part of the edit. I leave that for people that actually do work with that language and its silly indentation rules.

Comment: Everyone who clicked "recommend deletion" made the wrong decision. This answer might be less complete than desired, but it is not of such low quality that it should be deleted. It is an answer to the question, with a link to a bug in the official bug tracker. I wouldn't have posted it, but I certainly might appreciate it if I had this problem and came across the question. Surely at least *one* of the reviewers knew something about Python and could have edited the answer a bit? Everyone who knows me knows I'm all about quality, but we must be careful not to dump out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: @CodyGray The answer has been deleted now, I voted to undelete it.

Comment: @CodyGray it is undeleted now, does it need the edit I proposed here? Because I'm not a python dev so I can't judge the value of that solution correctly.

Comment: *I recommend against changing the code so late in the Python 2.7 release cycle. A change in behavior is too confusing.
And it's **not a bug but a design decision**, too. Over five years ago I implement parts of the IO interaction with the operating system for Python 3.0. I deliberately did NOT port modifications to 2.6.* - not a bug but a design decision and an long time ago one at that.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson that can be part of the edit I propose

Comment: Thanks for being on top of this, @rene. I'm not a python developer either, that's why I didn't make any edit to it while it was deleted. I don't feel qualified to improve the answer. At the same time, I have enough sense to realize that this might be useful to me if I *were* a python developer, so I don't think it should be deleted. Looks like Jarrod has edited in the information. Unfortunately, I see it already has picked up 2 delete votes. I honestly do not understand why people want this answer gone so badly. I see absolutely no way in which its mere presence is harmful.